# Unexpected crash using OCMock, mocking 'mutableCopy' on an NSString

Tags: ios, ocmock, gh-unit

I'm trying to mock a call to `mutableCopy` using OCMock and GHUnit on iOS.

Despite the test passing, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception during the cleanup, and I'm trying to work out why.

Take a look at this. This test shows that it is possible to mock `mutableCopy` on a mock `NSString`. In this test I return another `NSString`, not an `NSMutableString`. This is just to demonstrate that the `mutableCopy` expectation is fired, and the test passes.

```
#import <GHUnitIOS/GHUnit.h>
#import "OCMock.h"

@interface TestItClass : GHTestCase @end
@implementation TestItClass

// Test that mutableCopy on an NSString is mockable.
- (void)test_1_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAStringIsReturned {
    NSString *string = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSString.class];
    NSString *copy = @"foo";
    [(NSString *) [[(id) string expect] andReturn:copy] mutableCopy];

    // MutableCopy is mocked to return a string, not a mutable string!
    // This is clearly wrong from a static typing point of view, but
    // the test passes anyway, which is ok.
    NSMutableString *result = [string mutableCopy];
    GHAssertEquals(result, copy, nil);
    [(id)string verify];
}
```

Now I change the mock expectation so that `mutableCopy` now returns an `NSMutableString`. The test still passes, but on the tear down of the test I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

```
- (void)test_2_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAMutableStringIsReturned {
    NSString *string = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSString.class];
    NSMutableString *copy = [@"foo" mutableCopy];
    [(NSString *) [[(id) string expect] andReturn:copy] mutableCopy];

    // Now mutableCopy is mocked to return a mutable string!
    // The test now blows up during the test teardown! Why?
    NSMutableString *foo = [string mutableCopy];
    GHAssertEquals(foo, copy, nil);
    [(id)string verify];
}

@end
```

In both tests the verifies work, as to the asserts. This shows that both tests are well constructed and that the mock expectations are being fired as expected. However, the second test fails in the tear down with a bad memory access:

```
Simulator session started with process 7496
Debugger attached to process 7496
2013-03-11 18:23:05.519 UnitTests[7496:c07] TestItClass/test_2_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAMutableStringIsReturned ✘ 0.00s
2013-03-11 18:23:06.466 UnitTests[7496:c07] Re-running: TestItClass/test_2_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAMutableStringIsReturned <GHTest: 0x7793340>
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x11dfe3ea))
```

Can you please suggest to me why it might be happening?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Please include your `- (void)tearDown` methord in the question

Comment: There isn't an explicit tearDown; it's just the stock one that GHUnit provides.

Comment: @Shineeth Actually, it looks like the crash is in the teardown of one of the OCMock classes. I've posted part of the answer below.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in this test? There usually isn't any reason to mock core API methods that have well-defined behavior. There's probably a better way to achieve what you want to test.

Comment: Hi Christopher, sure, and I agree. Unfortunately in this case there is a fairly sophisticated output string being generated from the input, in relation to a small number of external well-tested builder classes. I don't want the implementation details of these to be a consideration of the test of the class that uses them. That requires that I mock their interactions with the mutable string which is accumulating their effects. Not ideal, but I'm unwilling to give up the encapsulation of concerns.

Comment: @Christopher Despite questions of ideal test construction, there shouldn't be any technical reason why this kind of test shouldn't work, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem your facing is caused by the fact that ARC follows the [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). Specifically this:

> - **You own any object you create**
>
>   You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

So the solution would be to look at the invocation selector to determine whether to `retain` the `returnValue` or not.

I hope this help.

Comment: The explanation provided by Zaygraveyard is right; and OCMock did not behave properly for methods that create objects. I have now implemented a solution. See https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/commit/00c0fe362de2b11625d348ae50379a108a3abf0b.

Comment: This is the bit that I was missing. I'm glad that we've found the bug in OCMock, and the maintainer has fixed it as a consequence. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm part way to understanding what is going on. I've compiled myself a debug library of `OCMock` so that I can understand where the crash is occurring.

Here's what I've found.

In my original test I call `andReturn:` to set a return expectation value:

```
NSMutableString *copy = [@"foo" mutableCopy];
[(NSString *) [[(id) string expect] andReturn:copy] mutableCopy];
```

This in turn calls `OCMReturnValueProvider` to store a `copy` so that it can returned at the appropriate time:

```
@implementation OCMReturnValueProvider

- (id)initWithValue:(id)aValue
{
    self = [super init];
    returnValue = [aValue retain];
    return self;
}
```

At this point the debugger says that `aValue` is of type `__NSCFString`. (Alarm bells ring in my head; isn't that a toll free bridge to an underlying string? Not a reference to the `NSMutableString`)

Next the test completes and passes.

However, the problem now occurs when the `OCMReturnValueProvider` is `dealloc`'d.

```
@implementation OCMReturnValueProvider
- (void)dealloc
{
    [returnValue release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The crash happens when `[returnValue release]` is called; the `OCMReturnValueProvider` is trying to release the `__NSCFString` that it `retain`ed earlier.

Next, I've switch on NSZombie debugging, which is revealing:

```
2013-03-12 20:58:19.654 UnitTests[16667:c07] TestItClass/test_2_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAMutableStringIsReturned  
2013-03-12 20:58:21.778 UnitTests[16667:c07] Re-running: TestItClass/test_2_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAMutableStringIsReturned <GHTest: 0x4afc5fd0>
2013-03-12 20:58:21.780 UnitTests[16667:c07] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b0b1fe0
```

The malloc-history (Find Zombie instrument) is helping shed some light on it:

```
Category            Event Type  Ref Ct  Responsible Caller
CFString (mutable)  Malloc        1     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Retain        2     -[OCMReturnValueProvider initWithValue:]
CFString (mutable)  Retain        3     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Retain        4     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Release       3     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Release       2     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Release       1     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Release       0     -[TestItClass test_2_mutable...]
CFString (mutable)  Zombie       -1     -[OCMReturnValueProvider dealloc]
```

So something in the test class is causing more releases than retains. Why's that happening? Strange!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more investigation I've discovered why the crash is occurring.

Let's look at the test again:

```
- (void)test_2_mutableCopyOfString_shouldBeMockable_givenAMutableStringIsReturned {
    NSString *string = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSString.class];
    NSMutableString *copy = [@"foo" mutableCopy];
    [(NSString *) [[(id) string expect] andReturn:copy] mutableCopy];

    NSMutableString *foo = [string mutableCopy];
}
```

What is happening is that the compiler is assuming that the object returned by `[string mutableCopy]` is was `retained` by `mutableCopy`, and so when `foo` is `dealloced` ARC does the equivalent of `[foo release]`.  This is a problem because we this object didn't have it's reference count increased within `andReturn:`.

I am confused as to why we don't see this behaviour with other objects configured to be returned by `andReturn:`. The `OCMReturnValueProvider` handling the mocked response is not `ARC` managed, and isn't retaining the returned value:

```
- (void)handleInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    [anInvocation setReturnValue:&returnValue];
}
```

So, the problem is simply solved by pre-emptively `retain`ing the returned value before setting it in the `NSInvocation`:

```
- (void)handleInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    [returnValue retain];
    [anInvocation setReturnValue:&returnValue];
}
```

This looks like a bug in `OCMock`. But given that problem doesn't occur in all circumstances, I'm not sure exactly. My fix works, but now runs the risk of leaking memory on objects which might not need this extra `retain`. However, a memory leak in a test, vs a test that doesn't run, is acceptable to me for now.

Comment: I've proposed this fix to the maintainer of OCMock. Will report back here once it's been resolved.

Comment: I believe the problem is that mutableCopy is somewhat special. Normally it's the responsibility of the caller to retain objects that they want to keep around. The called method returns the object with a "neutral" retain count. MutableCopy however returns an object with a +1 retain count. I saw the pull request but will try to find a solution that doesn't leak memory.

Comment: The explanation provided by Zaygraveyard is right; and OCMock did not behave properly for methods that create objects. I have now implemented a solution. See https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/commit/00c0fe362de2b11625d348ae50379a108a3abf0b.